# Database of trademarked words

Tags: data-request, data.gov

Does anybody know where I can download a complete & up to date database of trademarked words? I have found http://trademarks.reedtech.com/tmappxml.php but I'm looking for something that is already extracted and compiled into one database.

Any format will do.

Comment: For what country?

Comment: This incident happened in Bexar County.

Answer (score 5):

Check the following two resources (sorry, only US info):

1. http://www.uspto.gov/ip/officechiefecon/tm_casefiles.jsp
2. https://explore.data.gov/Business-Enterprise/Trademark-Daily-XML-Applications-Assignments-and-T/eqbw-esys

Hope this helps.